# SAMLv2 SP initiated: One Service Provider and multiple Identity Providers

Tags: .net, single-sign-on, saml

I need to use one Service Provider with multiple identity providers(idps) each idp is connected to the sp by using a subdomain i.e. http://subdomain1.mysite.com connects to idp1, http://subdomain2.mysite.com connects to idp2 etc then my Assertion Consumer Service URL looks like this https://mysite.com/SAML/AssertionConsumerService.aspx.

The problem is I need to know what idp the response is coming from in the AssertionConsumerService.aspx code so I can load in the right certificate. I've tried the issuer, response destination and other means with no luck.

Does anyone know a good way to differentiate between idps from the response and/or best practices? Or is there a standard way to do this?

I'm using http://www.componentspace.com/Products/SAMLv20.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In our system, we have an entity that represents the client (we call it a "service domain") and require that the client identify that entity by name either as the Issuer element value or the Issuer SPProvidedID attribute value.  SAML configuration on our end (SP) is associated with that "service domain" entity, including, for instance, the public key certificate for verifying their digital signature.

I'd say using the Issuer value is more appropriate than trying to key off subdomains.

Answer (score 2):

As you have noticed, if you have the same ACS URL for all IDPs, then the Destination will always be the same in the Assertion.

Each IDP should (must?) have its own unique Issuer at the very least if they also each have their own public cert they are signing with. In my experience, PingFederate and other servers ensure it is loading the correct configuration information when validating a Response. Not sure why Issuer wouldn't work for you in this situation as well.

You can get into situations where "different" IDPs from the same company may be sending you Responses with the same Issuer and different DSIG certs and AttributeStatements but that should not really happen in most cases.

HTH
Ian

Comment: Hi, thanks for the reply.  I could use the idp issuer i.e. the idp1 bit in https://subdomain.idp1.com and get the certificate based on that but it seems like a fix? Would you recommend the issuer way? I read that you can use the metadata-file from the idp but I don't think it's connected to a response(assertion). The main reason for using the same ACS URL was so you don't have to buy a SSL for each sp subdomain plus the duplicated code.

Comment: I agree with JST below. The "Issuer" element must be present in the message (per the Spec) and is part of the signed message (response or Assertion) IIRC. You should rely upon that.